# How to compare a data from response.body

Tags: flutter, dart

```
void getData() {
    var url = 'https://172.20.10.3/lockertest/getData.php';
    http.get(url).then((response) {
    var data = "${response.body}";
    var name = "1";
    print("${response.body}");
    print("$data" == "$name");
    });
  }
```

I try to compare "$data" == "$name" but result is false

```
I/flutter (27601): 1
I/flutter (27601): false
```

```
void getData() {
    var url = 'https://172.20.10.3/lockertest/getData.php';
    http.get(url).then((response) {
    var data = "${response.body}";
    var name = “test”;
    print("${response.body}");
    print("$data" == "$name");
    });
  }
```

I try to compare "$data" == "$name" and result sill false

```
I/flutter (27601): test
I/flutter (27601): false
```

Comment: Try to compare int value instead of string. JSON in response may contains not only string values.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a String (name) to an int (response.body). Remove the "" from the var name and it should work